# How did kid + nap come to mean abduct?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, history

Why do the words kid and nap become kidnap as a meaning of abduct, when did that take form and why?

Additionally, if nap is really nab, why did nab become nap?

Comment: Have you looked up the word in a good dictionary (and maybe, further)?

Comment: @Shmuel Google now finds [etymology results](https://www.google.es/search?q=kidnap+etymology). That means that, if you are curious about the origin of words, you can find a lot of them by just googling `<word> etymology`. It won't find every case, but it's a good quick starting point :)

Comment: So if you haven't even looked in a dictionary, would you agree that the downvote reason "does not show any research effort" apply?

Comment: @pipe Educating users that they should research before asking is good, but some users don't get the rhetorical question - "tone is hard to decipher online". Just use "normal sentence" instead.

Comment: @user314366 It is not a rhetorical question - it's a genuine question I would like an answer to. I have seen that some users show a complete disregard for any policies but other users are simply not aware of them.

Answer (score 9):

From etymology online:

**Kidnap**: https://www.etymonline.com/word/kidnap#etymonline_v_1845

> 1680s, thieves' cant, a compound of kid (n.) "child" and nap (v.) "snatch away," which probably is a variant of nab (v.). Perhaps a back-formation from kidnapper, which is recorded earlier. Originally "to steal children to provide servants and laborers in the American colonies."

**Nab**: https://www.etymonline.com/word/nab

> "to catch (someone)," 1680s, probably a variant of dialectal nap "to seize, catch, lay hold of" (1670s, now surviving only in kidnap), which possibly is from Scandinavian

`when did that take form and why?`

There is no mystery behind it. **Nap** is a spelling variant of **nab**.

Comment: In the words of Terry Pratchett, `It's written in Old, before they invented spelling`.

Comment: @Separatrix One of my many favorite Pratchett quotes.

Comment: Those who are down voting should also explain the reason.